# How can I create an @property with dynamic sub-attributes?

Tags: python

I have a class, `Tariff`, with a quantity and some prices:

```
class Tariff():
    quantity = 0
    item_1_price = 250
    item_1_selected = False
    item_2_price = 350
    item_2_selected = False
    item_3_price = 165
    item_3_selected = False

    @property
    def total(self):
        return sum([
            self.item_1_price * self.item_1_selected,
            self.item_2_price * self.item_2_selected,
            self.item_3_price * self.item_3_selected,
            ]) * self.quantity
```

I can use it as such:

```
purchase = Tariff()
purchase.quantity = 2
purchase.item_1_selected = True
purchase.item_2_selected = True
print(purchase.total)
> 1200
```

I want a function that will tell me the total of an individual item.
For example:

```
print(purchase.totals.item_1)
> 500
```

What is the best way of going around this? Is this possible/easy?

Comment: One time you wrote `total` (singular), the other time you wrote `totals` (plural). Are these supposed to be the same property, or two separate properties?

Comment: @Aran-Fey one is the overall total, one is meant to be an attribute with all the subtotals as sub-attributes

Comment: Note also that you probably shouldn't have this data structure. Why not making an `Item` a `namedtuple` (or a class itself) and have a list of items instead?

Comment: @AdamSmith This is a simplification of something I'm doing with sqlalchemy, so the tariff object is actually a sqlalchemy model

Comment: @user1518321 I can't imagine *any* underlying data structure where this is the proper model, is all.

Comment: @AdamSmith Legacy data structure :')

Comment: @christophski ETL is your friend ;). Though in your shoes I would probably just create a better-behaved wrapper around your legacy data so it plays nice in memory, along with `staticmethods` to load and dump between the wrapper and the SQL model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) that returns a subclass of `int` with the `__getattr__` method overridden to obtain the total of a given individual item on the fly:

```
class Tariff:
    quantity = 0
    item_1_price = 250
    item_1_selected = False
    item_2_price = 350
    item_2_selected = False
    item_3_price = 165
    item_3_selected = False

    class TotalProperty:
        def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
            class Total(int):
                def __getattr__(self, item):
                    return getattr(obj, item + '_price') * getattr(obj, item + '_selected') * obj.quantity

            return Total(sum([
                obj.item_1_price * obj.item_1_selected,
                obj.item_2_price * obj.item_2_selected,
                obj.item_3_price * obj.item_3_selected,
                ]) * obj.quantity)

    total = TotalProperty()
```

so that:

```
purchase = Tariff()
purchase.quantity = 2
purchase.item_1_selected = True
purchase.item_2_selected = True
print(purchase.total)
print(purchase.total.item_1)
print(purchase.total.item_2)
print(purchase.total.item_3)
```

would output:

```
1200
500
700
0
```

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward way of doing it would be:

```
@property
def total(self):
    return dict(
        sum=sum([ self.item_1_price * self.item_1_selected,
                  self.item_2_price * self.item_2_selected,
                  self.item_3_price * self.item_3_selected,
                ]) * self.quantity,
        item_1=item_1_price,
        item_2=item_2_price,
        item_3=item_3_price)
```

Then this would return a dictionary containing all wanted information.  To access the elements in the dict you would need to use the indexing syntax, though:

```
print(purchase.totals['item_1'])
> 500
```

If you can live with this, this is what I would go for.

If you *need* to have attributes, you would need to create an object which contains these attributes (or at least fakes them).  Have a look at `collections.namedtuple` for this:

```
Totals = collections.namedtuple('total',
                                ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'sum'])
return Totals(sum=sum([ self.item_1_price * self.item_1_selected,
                        self.item_2_price * self.item_2_selected,
                        self.item_3_price * self.item_3_selected,
                     ]) * self.quantity,
              item_1=item_1_price,
              item_2=item_2_price,
              item_3=item_3_price)
```

Then you could use:

```
print(purchase.totals.item_1)
> 500
```